# Codeigniter: Remove a URI segment on specific controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, uri

I have a controller named `cart` with many functions.

I need ONLY for this specific controller, to "redirect" the second segment to another one, specifically:

`http://www.domain.com/cart/music` should show the `cart/show/music` function.

I tried doing:

```
class Cart extends MY_Controller {

    public function show(){
        $routes['cart/musica'] = 'cart/show/$1';
        //More code...
    }

}
```

This is what I saw on other answers but can't make it work and actually doesn't seem right to me.

This 'redirect' should only be valid for some of the functions in `Cart class`.
How can this be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write into `/application/config/routes.php`

```
$route['cart/music'] = 'cart/show/$1';
```

**Note:** Use `$route` instead of `$routes`

If you want to set dynamic, use like this one. Regex is allow `alpha-numeric` chars

```
$route['cart/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = 'cart/show/$1';
```

Or you can allow all chars with `any` but this is not logical:

```
$route['cart/(:any)'] = 'cart/show/$1';
```

Comment: Is there a way to set an array of those? I need some of them to be like that `cart/music`, `cart/books`, `cart/film` etc...

Comment: Ok, tks! I'll try adding a dynamic way to handle this, but for now it works!

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/routes.php` add the following,

```
 $route['cart/(:alpha)'] = "cart/show/$1";
```